# How to load pdf files to recycler view in fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

ello guys good day I'm trying to make an app using android java but I'm stuck any idea would be appreciated

I'm trying to access all pdf files in android device using the media store and cursor but it's not working the aim is to display all pdf files in a recycler view on a fragment the issue here is that it never displays meaning maybe the data wasn't passed because when the arraylist is populated manually it displays otherwise non I've checked the log but I can't seem to find anything.

This my fragment code

```
public class AllFragment extends Fragment {
    View view;
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
    ArrayList<String> pdfList;
    
    
    private final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;

    private Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mActivity = (Activity) context;
    }
    
    
    public void checkPermission(){
        
        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
        {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(mActivity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
                    .setTitle("Permission needed")
                    .setMessage("Allow "+getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)+" to access your storage?")
                    .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity,
                                                              new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
                        }
                    } 
                )
                .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Please allow this permission!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    
                })
                .create().show();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity,
                                                  new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
    //checkPermission();
    
    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.AllFragment, container, false);
        //pdfList = getPdfList();
        //buildData();
        //LinearLayoutManager
        //pdfList = new String[] {"one", "two", "three", "fou4", "five", "six"};
        
        getPdfList();
        initRecyclerView(view);
        return view;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        checkPermission();
    }
    
    
    //RecyclerView
    public void initRecyclerView(View view){
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.allPdfsRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        AllPdfAdapter adapter = new AllPdfAdapter(pdfList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    
    
   
   
    
    public ArrayList<String> getPdfList() {
        pdfList = new ArrayList<>();
        Uri collection;
        
        final String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
        };

        final String sortOrder = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";

        final String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ?";

        final String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf");
        final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{mimeType};

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            collection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
        }else{
            collection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
        }


        try (Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(collection, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder)) {
            assert cursor != null;

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnData = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA);
                int columnName = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                //ArrayList pdfList = new ArrayList<>();
                do {
                    pdfList.add((cursor.getString(columnData)));
                    System.out.println(cursor.getString(columnData));
                    Log.d(TAG, "getPdf: " + cursor.getString(columnData));
                    //you can get your pdf files
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        return pdfList;
    }
    
    
}
```

This my adapter code

```
public class AllPdfAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllPdfAdapter.My_ViewHolder>
{
    private ArrayList<String> data;
    
    
    public AllPdfAdapter(ArrayList<String>data){
        this.data = data;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public AllPdfAdapter.My_ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup p1, int p2)
    {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(p1.getContext());
        View v = li.inflate(R.layout.allList,p1,false);
        
        // TODO: Implement this method
        return new My_ViewHolder(v);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AllPdfAdapter.My_ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        String title = data.get(position);
        holder.ttt.setText(title);
        
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        return data.size();
    }
    
    
    public class My_ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        
        ImageView iii;
        TextView ttt;
        
        public My_ViewHolder (View v){
            super(v);
            
            iii = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
            ttt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Your answers will be appreciated.

Comment: where are you adding `notifyDataSetChanged`? for the adapter

Comment: No need for notifyDataSetChanged. He passes the data in the Adapter's constructor. Have you tested that getPdfList() returns a non-empty list?

Comment: How do I test that @gioravered

Comment: Either print the result of getPdfList() or add a breakpoint, run in debug mode and check the returned value.

Comment: You're right @gioravered why it returns an empty list is what I don't understand and what can I do to change that.